# Markdown editor for OSX (ssh connection) navigate through ftp folder to load and upload modified .md

Tags: osx, offline, text-editor, markdown

I'm looking for a OSX desktop application in which I can edit plain markdown documents. I found many but none with ssh connection to navigate and choose which .md have to edit. I try [ulysse app](http://ulyssesapp.com/) but only connect to google drive, icloud etc. [Stackedit](https://stackedit.io/) great but no navigation throught server. So if anyone have tips.

Answer (score 0):

[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) and [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) are great syntax hightlighting editors that support remotely editing documents via sftp. See this question and answer on [Syntax Hightlighting Editors](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/905/287) for more info.